# Getting Null when trying to query the path to my button element

Tags: javascript, html, null, innerhtml, queryselector

**Issue**:

I want to return the button Element within my document that matches the specified selector, in this case `".comment-body__interaction--delete"` but keep getting a return of null every time I `console.log` the variable that contains the return element.

**Background Info**

1. The HTML element I'm Trying to target has been inserted into the document via innerHTML.
2. All my scripts are at the bottom of the index.html page
3. I'm using querySelector at the bottom of the js document.
4. I know my class name is correct because I can style it via CSS.

***my code***

```
// LOCATION VARIABLES ***
const conversation = document.querySelector('.conversation-container-posted');
const form = document.querySelector('form');
console.log(form);
// Array THAT HOLDS ALL MY COMMENT OBJECTS
let objectsArray;

// VARIABLE THAT HOLDS MY HTML TEMPLATE
const template = (singleCommentObj) => {
  return `
  <article class="comment-container">
  <figure class="comment-container__picture">
    <img class="comment-container__picture-img" src="${singleCommentObj.image}" alt="profile picture" />
  </figure>
  <div class="comment-body">
    <h3 class="comment-body__name">${singleCommentObj.name}</h3>
    <div class="comment-body__date">${singleCommentObj.date}</div>
    <article class="comment-body__comment"><p>${singleCommentObj.comment}</p></article>
    <div class="comment-body__interaction">
      <div class="comment-body__interaction--likes">Likes</div>
      <button id="${singleCommentObj.id}" class="comment-body__interaction--delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </article>
  <hr class="comment-container__divider"/>
  `;
};

const displayComment = (object) => {
  let staticComments = object
    .sort((a, b) => b.timestamp - a.timestamp)
    .map((values) => {
      values.image = 'https://loremflickr.com/48/48';
      values.date = moment.unix(values.timestamp / 1000).fromNow();
      return template(values);
    })
    .join('');
  conversation.innerHTML = staticComments;
};

// Gets AN ARRAY OF OBJECTS FROM THE api AND ASSIGNS IT TO objectsArray
// CALLS displayComment WITH objectsArray AS A PARAMETER TO INSERT ITS CONTENT INTO THE DOM
axios
  .get('https://project-1-api.herokuapp.com/comments?api_key=7d8d085e-486e-42dc-b836-58009cbfa68f')
  .then((response) => {
    objectsArray = response.data;
    displayComment(objectsArray);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let fluidObject = new FormData(e.target);
  fluidObject = Object.fromEntries(fluidObject);
  axios
    .post('https://project-1-api.herokuapp.com/comments?api_key=7d8d085e-486e-42dc-b836-58009cbfa68f&content-type=application/json', {
      name: fluidObject.name,
      comment: fluidObject.comment,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      objectsArray.push(response.data);
      displayComment(objectsArray);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});

// DELETE
const a = document.querySelector('.comment-body__interaction--delete');
console.log(a);
```

**This console.log(a) returns NULL**

Answer (score 0):

The code that creates the said element, `displayComment` is in an asynchronous actions callback.

You have to wait for the action to complete before you try to access the element.

In other words `const a = document.querySelector('.comment-body__interaction--delete');` executes before your request was successful and the elements were created.

Comment: That makes sense, how can I make sure displayComment has finished its request? from my point of view the posting of the HTML was successful and finished. (obviously is not).

Comment: You have to put the code inside `.then((response) => {
      objectsArray.push(response.data);
      displayComment(objectsArray);
     const a = document.querySelector('.comment-body__interaction--delete');
    })`

Code outside it will execute immediately waiting for the request to succeed

Comment: Thank you T J !!